# Replace éàçè... with equivalent "eace" In GWT

Tags: gwt, unicode, normalization, utf, unicode-normalization

I tried
`s=Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`
But it seems that GWT API doesn't provide such fonction.

I tried also :

```
s=s.replace("é",e);
```

But it doesn't work either

The scenario is I'am trying to générate token from the clicked Widget's text for the history management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@okrasz, the `foldToASCII()` worked but I found a shorter one [Transform a String to URL standard String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205375/transform-a-string-to-url-standard-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You can take ASCII folding filter from Lucene and add to your project. You can just take `foldToASCII()` method from [`ASCIIFoldingFilter`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java) (the method does not have any dependencies). There is also a patch in Jira that has a full class for that without any dependencies - [see here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12386658/UnicodeCharUtil.java). It should be compiled by GWT without any problems. License should be also OK, since it is Apache License, but don't quote me on it - you should ask a real lawyer.