# Unicode normalization in GWT

Tags: gwt, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization, text-normalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace éàçè… with equivalent “eace” In GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500673/replace-eace-with-equivalent-eace-in-gwt)

Is there some library I can use to make unicode normalization operations in gwt? (to contextually guarantee that the latin O is equal to the Cyrillic O, for instance)

Comment: AFAICT, Unicode normalization won't help you. Normalization is about always representing things like diacritics as either 1 or 2 codepoints, so that `à` always compares equal to `à` whether it's originally written as U+00E0 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE) or U+0300 U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A, COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT) (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0/index.htm)

Comment: A similar question has been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7501964/291741, and I think using (or maybe slightly adjusting) the `ASCIIFoldingFilter.foldToASCII()` method should work